# Shortcut to change the search engine in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> takes me to the search field, but how can I change the search engine (say from Stack Overflow to Ask Ubuntu) using the keyboard?

Comment: was there not a feature allowing something like:  "so foo" which would then search stackoverflow for "foo"?  Assuming that "so" was configured.  I have this setup but can't recall how it was done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. That should open the search engine selection menu in Firefox.